# How can I execute multiple, simultaneous jquery effects?

Tags: jquery, animation, effects, jquery-animate, effect

I am animating some error/validation elements on a page.  I want them to bounce and be highlighted, but at the same time if possible.  Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
var els = $(".errorMsg");
els.effect("bounce", {times: 5}, 100);
els.effect("highlight", {color: "#ffb0aa"}, 300);
```

This causes the elements to first bounce, and THEN be highlighted, and I'd like them to occur simultaneously.  I know that with `.animate()` you can specify `queue:false` in the options, but I don't want to use animate because the pre-built effects "bounce" and "highlight" are exactly what I want.

I have tried simply chaining the calls like `els.effect().effect()`, and that doesn't work.  I've also tried to put `queue:false` in the options object I pass in, and that doesn't work.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.4.2, UI 1.7.2.  So, latest stable of both at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so this is a very custom solution that combines the bounce and highlight effects.  I'd rather see some kind of jquery support for combining these more easily, specifying {queue:false}, but I don't think it's that simple.

What I did was take the jquery.effects.bounce.js and jquery.effects.highlight.js (from jquery-ui-1.8rc3), and combine the code of the two as DaveS suggested, to create a new effect named "hibounce".  In my testing, it supports all of the options of both, and they occur simultaneously.  It looks great!  I'm not a *huge* fan of solutions like this though, because of the maintenance factor.  Anytime I upgrade jquery.ui, I'll have to update this file manually as well.

Anyway, here is the combined result (jquery.effects.hibounce.js)

```
(function($) {

$.effects.hibounce = function(o) {
    return this.queue(function() {
        // Highlight and bounce parts, combined
        var el = $(this),
            props = ['position','top','left','backgroundImage', 'backgroundColor', 'opacity'],
            mode = $.effects.setMode(el, o.options.mode || 'show'),
            animation = {
                backgroundColor: el.css('backgroundColor')
            };

        // From highlight
        if (mode == 'hide') {
            animation.opacity = 0;
        }

        $.effects.save(el, props);

        // From bounce
        // Set options
        var mode = $.effects.setMode(el, o.options.mode || 'effect'); // Set Mode
        var direction = o.options.direction || 'up'; // Default direction
        var distance = o.options.distance || 20; // Default distance
        var times = o.options.times || 5; // Default # of times
        var speed = o.duration || 250; // Default speed per bounce
        if (/show|hide/.test(mode)) props.push('opacity'); // Avoid touching opacity to prevent clearType and PNG issues in IE


        // Adjust
        $.effects.save(el, props); el.show(); // Save & Show
        $.effects.createWrapper(el); // Create Wrapper
        var ref = (direction == 'up' || direction == 'down') ? 'top' : 'left';
        var motion = (direction == 'up' || direction == 'left') ? 'pos' : 'neg';
        var distance = o.options.distance || (ref == 'top' ? el.outerHeight({margin:true}) / 3 : el.outerWidth({margin:true}) / 3);
        if (mode == 'show') el.css('opacity', 0).css(ref, motion == 'pos' ? -distance : distance); // Shift
        if (mode == 'hide') distance = distance / (times * 2);
        if (mode != 'hide') times--;

        // from highlight
        el
            .show()
            .css({
                backgroundImage: 'none',
                backgroundColor: o.options.color || '#ffff99'
            })
            .animate(animation, {
                queue: false,
                duration: o.duration * times * 1.3, // cause the hilight to finish just after the bounces (looks best)
                easing: o.options.easing,
                complete: function() {
                    (mode == 'hide' && el.hide());
                    $.effects.restore(el, props);
                    (mode == 'show' && !$.support.opacity && this.style.removeAttribute('filter'));
                    (o.callback && o.callback.apply(this, arguments));
                    el.dequeue();
                }
            });

        // Animate bounces
        if (mode == 'show') { // Show Bounce
            var animation = {opacity: 1};
            animation[ref] = (motion == 'pos' ? '+=' : '-=') + distance;
            el.animate(animation, speed / 2, o.options.easing);
            distance = distance / 2;
            times--;
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) { // Bounces
            var animation1 = {}, animation2 = {};
            animation1[ref] = (motion == 'pos' ? '-=' : '+=') + distance;
            animation2[ref] = (motion == 'pos' ? '+=' : '-=') + distance;
            el.animate(animation1, speed / 2, o.options.easing).animate(animation2, speed / 2, o.options.easing);
            distance = (mode == 'hide') ? distance * 2 : distance / 2;
        };
        if (mode == 'hide') { // Last Bounce
            var animation = {opacity: 0};
            animation[ref] = (motion == 'pos' ? '-=' : '+=')  + distance;
            el.animate(animation, speed / 2, o.options.easing, function(){
                el.hide(); // Hide
                $.effects.restore(el, props); $.effects.removeWrapper(el); // Restore
                if(o.callback) o.callback.apply(this, arguments); // Callback
            });
        } else {
            var animation1 = {}, animation2 = {};
            animation1[ref] = (motion == 'pos' ? '-=' : '+=') + distance;
            animation2[ref] = (motion == 'pos' ? '+=' : '-=') + distance;
            el.animate(animation1, speed / 2, o.options.easing).animate(animation2, speed / 2, o.options.easing, function(){
                $.effects.restore(el, props); $.effects.removeWrapper(el); // Restore
                if(o.callback) o.callback.apply(this, arguments); // Callback
            });
        };
        el.queue('fx', function() { el.dequeue(); });
        el.dequeue();
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

It can be used like any other effect now:

```
var el = $("#div1");
el.effect("hibounce", {color: "#F00", times: 5}, 100);
```

Answer (score 12):

jQuery UI will queue the effects by default. Use dequeue() to run simultaneously:

```
    var opt = {duration: 7000};

    $('#lbl').effect('highlight', opt).dequeue().effect('bounce', opt);
```

[Demo in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HoffZ/hBEmR/)

Comment: This doesn't actually work the way it appears to. Try reversing bounce and highlight and you'll see that they are not really occurring simultaneously.

Comment: You're right @CharlesWood. It doesn't work when 'hightlight' is before 'bounce'. I've played around a bit with the fiddle: Other effects, like 'blind', 'puff' and 'fold, works ok with highlight last. Seems to be an issue with bounce before highlight. Not sure why

Answer (score 4):

jQuery UI's effects queue animations, so write your own version of a bounce/highlight function. Just copy the source code from both into a single function, clean up the code, and each time it calls animate, make sure to have the bounce and highlight logic in there together.

Comment: I've considered this option, and I may fall back on it if I really really need both effects.  For now, I'm content to have the code simpler, and use just 1 of the effects.  It's too bad that jquery allows you to specify {queue:false} for calls to animate(), but not effect().

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var els = $(".errorMsg");
setTimeout(function() {
    els.effect("bounce", {times: 5}, 100);
}, 1);
setTimeout(function() {
    els.effect("highlight", {color: "#ffb0aa"}, 300);
}, 1);
```

That should call both the effects at roughly the same time, asynchronously.

Comment: I'll give this a shot tomorrow when I'm back at the code, if it works, I'll vote up and mark as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I doubt this will work while the straight forward method fails. You are still calling the `effect` function one by one. Remember Javascript is ran single threaded, so both are going to execute linearly.

Comment: LiraNuna called it.  The animations still queue, and the effects execute one after the other.  However, LiraNuna, while javascript might be single threaded, it is possible to have 2 effects execute in a way that appears to be simultaneous.  You can certainly do it using jquery's animate(), by providing {queue:false} in the options.  Before multi-threaded/multi-core CPUs, OSes used time slicing to run multiple threads.  JS isn't all that different.

Comment: Good call, LiraNuna. I've had good luck using this technique to get "background" JS working - browsers run setTimeout functions asynchronously. jQuery's effects must run synchronously regardless.