# How to make two jQuery animations play simultaneously?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have these two things happen in my jQuery-animated website:

```
$('#myFirstDiv').animate({top: "15%"}, 3000); 
$('#mySecondDiv').animate({bottom: "15%"}, 3000);
```

These two animations seem to happen one after another, rather than simultaneously. There's a slight delay before the second one plays, about one tenth of a second. I want to make them occur simultaneously.

I tried this:

```
$('#myFirstDiv').animate({top: "15%"}, 3000); 
$('#mySecondDiv').animate({bottom: "15%"}, {duration:3000, queue: false});
```

but it's probably wrong.

I would appreciate advice on how to do this correctly.

Comment: Can you throw your code into jsFiddle.net so we can test it?

Comment: When you say "it's probably wrong", do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Working as intended here http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/gYTYN/ ?

Comment: Thank you Niklas. Interesting. It does work as intended. maybe I'm misunderstanding something. When the two statements follow one another like this, aren't they supposed to play one after another? I'm asking because there does seem to be slight delay on my site between the first and second animations.

Comment: @Abe I was about to, but Niklas beat me to it.

Comment: @lonesomeday I mean it doesn't *appear* to work. There seems to be a very slight deleay between the two animations, whether I use it or not.

Comment: I think I do. It's a subjective thing. There appears to be a microsecond delay, which in my case makes the site look a little too rough.

Comment: Do you see the same slight delay in jsFiddle?

Comment: No, but the initial position in the fiddle is different. My secondDiv also slides up, not down. I'm placing the URL to the site in the edited question, may I please ask you to take a look.

Comment: Put a function in a callcack and they will play one after another.  Put them right next to each other and they will play simultaneously.

Comment: @Lime, so you're saying that the way they are written now, they are supposed to play simultaneously?

Comment: Here is a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344804/how-can-i-execute-multiple-simultaneous-jquery-effects

Comment: Thank you Calvin. Yes, there is a certain similarity, but I think it's only superficial. I am animating two separate divs with identical effect, not one element with two different effects. One way or another, I don't think this challenge should require a page of code as a solution. There has to be a simpler answer.

Comment: For the sake of curiosity and to eliminate any perceptual subjectiveness from the test.. I made a jsfiddle with the elems animated side-by-side: http://jsfiddle.net/5a3k/e6Fmb/  I dont see any delay..

Comment: Could you try it like this: animate the 1st one up from top:300% to top:15%; animate the 2nd one up from bottom:-200% to bottom:15% ?

Comment: Here's my version: http://jsfiddle.net/e6Fmb/6/ See the delay?

Comment: There is no delay, one animation is just taking longer then the other.  You have one set to bottom and the other set to top.

Comment: Yes, you're right Lime. I made a math mistake. It's supposed to be top: 300% and bottom:-270%. Then the animations play synchronously. I am glad I asked the question though, because it helped me to find the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work just fine. Animation in jQuery is asynchronous, this means that if you have two animation calls, the second one will get called right after the first one even though the first animation is still in progress. If at any point you want to have the first one to execute to the end before the second one, your code will look like

```
$('#myFirstDiv').animate({top: "15%"}, 3000, function(){
  $('#mySecondDiv').animate({bottom: "15%"}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Everything looks fine here, although it is smoother in chrome than in firefox. [I forgot to click "Add Comment" lol, I've had this open for 2 hours]