# multiple jquery effects multiple times at specific timing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, delay, jquery-effects

I've got this piece of code:

```
$("#au").click(function(){
    $("#sca").delay(18625).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scb").delay(26520).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scc").delay(30884).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scd").delay(34901).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#sce").delay(39000).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scf").delay(44000).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scg").delay(45000).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#sca").delay(51000).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scb").delay(52000).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scc").delay(53000).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scd").delay(55000).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#sce").delay(56000).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scf").delay(57300).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scg").delay(61403).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#sca").delay(67500).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scb").delay(68200).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scc").delay(69200).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scd").delay(71400).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#sce").delay(72300).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scf").delay(73000).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#scg").delay(77500).effect("bounce","highlight",2000);
    $("#au-sca").get(0).play();
});
```

Problem is, only `bounce` is working, not `highlight` (that isn't such a pity, it's just a wish). And the second and third 'loops' are not triggering at correct times, but like a minute or so later. Is there any known an proven way to overcome these 2 obstacles & make the code less obtrusive in the mean time?

Comment: Well, it's an 'animation' in sync with a song, but I can't put it up online.

Comment: @user1718397: You don't have to put the whole thing online, just enough to demonstrate the problem you are having. Beside, I think you'll find Darrrrrren (or however many r's that's supposed to be) below has your answer. `effect` doesn't allow you to use multiple effects at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the jQuery UI effect function only takes one effect at a time - thus the second parameter you are specifying is actually being interpreted as an option that (obviously) doesn't exist.

Your issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344804/how-can-i-execute-multiple-simultaneous-jquery-effects) question, where the answer actually combines the very two effects you are attempting to combine.  I believe the answer to that question is exactly what you'll need.