# Is there a simple way to do two jQuery effects right after each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Basically, I have a div that I want to apply a `highlight` and `bounce` effect to.

If I do just one, it works fine. But combining them seems to be much more tricky than I expected.

I tried to do simply this:

```
$('.highlight_on_success').bind("ajax:success", function(){$(this).closest('div.social-comment').effect('highlight').effect('bounce');});
```

But that didn't work, then I did some reading and I tried using `dequeue()` like so:

```
$('.highlight_on_success').bind("ajax:success", function(){$(this).closest('div.social-comment').effect('highlight').dequeue().effect('bounce');});
```

But that too didn't work.

I eventually stumbled across [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360710/91970) about something similar, but that feels WAAAAAYYY too heavy.

Is there a simpler, more native, less hacky, way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Can you describe _"didn't work"_? ,  create stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: CSS3 transitions would work instead of `highlight` if they don't play well together. Actually would work for both effects and all you would need is toggle a class

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a function callback to `effect()`:

```
$('.highlight_on_success').bind("ajax:success", function () {
    var obj = $(this).closest('div.social-comment');
    obj.closest('div.social-comment').effect('highlight', function() {
        obj.effect('bounce');
    });
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't make the object bounce. The highlight works, it just doesn't bounce. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX success function can be used like this:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
     url: 'ajax_processor_file.php',
    data: {varName : varValue}
});

xhr.done(function(){
    $('.highlight_on_success')
        .closest('div.social-comment')
        .addClass('highlightMyDiv')
        .effect( "bounce", {times:3}, 300, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('highlightMyDiv');
        });
});
```

or just:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
     url: 'ajax_processor_file.php',
    data: {varName : varValue}
})
.done(function(){
    $('.highlight_on_success')
        .closest('div.social-comment')
        .addClass('highlightMyDiv')
        .effect( "bounce", {times:3}, 300, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('highlightMyDiv');
        });
});
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.social-comment')
        .addClass('highlightMyDiv')
        .effect( "bounce", {times:3}, 300, function(){
          $(this).removeClass('highlightMyDiv');
    });
});
```

```css
.highlightMyDiv{background:wheat;border:1px solid orange;color:brown;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="social-comment">
  The social comment div
</div>
<button>Simulate AJAX Callback</button>
```

---

Notes:

(1) The `.effect()` method is part of jQueryUI, so that library must be referenced/included.

(2) You can add the CSS using `addClass` and chain jQuery methods as above.

(3) Above code is not hijacking the AJAX function; it is the best practices methodology for writing an ajax routine, [as per the jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

(4) In the previous person's answer, perhaps the DIV is not bouncing because the jQueryUI library is not included? Note that `.effect()` is not part of jQuery, it is part of jQueryUI - but you can also [load just the effects plugin individually](https://plugins.jquery.com/ui.effect-bounce/).

(5) Note that `.bind()` has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 in favor of `.on()` (virtually the same syntax).

Comment: Is there no way to do that without manually hijacking the `.ajax` function?